# Unbalanced control and experiment group sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, unbalanced-classes, group-differences

I am working on testing the significance of a training program for businesses. We offer the training to the experimental group and want to compare some metrics to the control group. Because it takes time to implement such training, currently we only have $n=10$ for the experiment group and $n=150$ for the control group.

Should I use the whole control group to compare the metrics or should I do random sampling and test out different experiment:control ratios? I'm also thinking about picking businesses from the control group that that are more similar to the experiment group (same types of product, etc) - does it make sense to do so?

I'm super new to experimental design/testing so any advice is appreciated. Note that I have to use that experimental group for now and it's not possible to increase the size of experimental group at this point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for group comparisons that data should be balanced (but, if you can plan to get equal group sizes, that is usually better).  You should analyze the data you have. Of course experimental group size of 10 might be few, but you do not better the situation by subsampling the larger group.

For more advice, we need more details of the situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What of additional details should i provide?

Comment: In what does the experimental treatment consist? What are the units? (businesses? What kind of ...)   In short, describe the experiment and your goal in everyday language.

Comment: Sure! So as mentioned, we provide training programs to companies and want to see if there is a significant difference in some metrics for companies that went through the training program. The units are companies. The experiment group contains companies that already did the training program, and the control group contains those that did not. We want to compare metrics like: time to complete a certain task of the group of companies who did the training vs who did not and see if the difference is significant

Comment: I do realize that such metric could be influenced by other factors (company size, industry, type of products, etc) of the company, I wonder if I should subsample the control group to find those that are most comparable to those in the experimental group

Comment: Please add this new details to the Q as an edit!

Comment: To make the parenthetical point about equal sample size a bit more clear, this means that if you have a fixed total N, you'll get the best power by splitting equally between groups. But more data is always better, there'd be no reason to limit your sampling just to keep the groups equally sized.